# What is the best practices for oracle XMLType to RDMS migration?

Tags: xml, database, oracle, oracle11g, xmltype

We are storing XBRL files (basically XML) into oracle 11.2 as XMLType. Each XML files containing more than 500 tags. For reporting purpose we are extracting around 200 values from XML files to normal tables (NORMAL_TABLE).Reading from XML file directly is taking more execution time so we are doing migration as job from XMLType to NORMAL_TABLE. Basically each row in NORMAL_TABLE represent each XML files, that mean now we have around 200 columns in NORMAL_TABLE.

Because of new requirement and CR , now we need more values to be migrate from XML to NORMAL_TABLE. Which would be the best practices for this case? Is it ok to add more columns into NORMAL_TABLE ?